# Symfony2 Form Collection don't check for id

Tags: forms, rest, symfony, collections

I don't know if this a configuration issue or work as intended anhd i don't use it properly. But when i send a PUT request with entity A which contain a collection of entity B the method bind try to overwrite the properties of the entities B.

Example :

GET Entity A :

```
{ 
  id : 1,
  name : "test",
  collection : [
      0 : { id : 2, name : "Entity B - 2", line : 0, property : "stuff" },
      1 : { id : 3, name : "Entity B - 3", line : 1  }
  ]
 }
```

PUT Entity A : (removed the entity B id 2 from the collection )

```
{ 
  id : 1,
  name : "test",
  collection : [
      0 : { id : 3, name : "Entity B - 3", line : 0 }
  ]
 }
```

Result :

```
{ 
  id : 1,
  name : "test",
  collection : [
      0 : { id : 2, name : "Entity B - 3", line : 0, property : "stuff" }
  ]
 }
```

Configuration :

**EntityA**

```
     /**
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"line" = "ASC"})
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="entityB", mappedBy="entityA", cascade= { "persist", "remove"})
     */
     private $collection;

     public function addCollection($entityB)
     {
          $this->collection[] = $entityB;
          $lines->setEntityA($this);

          return $this;
      }

     public function removeCollection($entityB)
     {
         $this->collection->removeElement($entityB);
         $lines->setEntityA(null);
      }
```

**EntityB**

```
     /**
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="entityA", inversedBy="collection")
      */
      private $entityA;
```

**Controller**

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new $entityAType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

**Form**

```
    ->add('collection', 'collection', array(
                                        "type" => new entityBType,
                                        'allow_add' => true,
                                        'allow_delete' => true,
                                        'by_reference' => false,
                                        'cascade_validation' => true,
                                    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using a event listener which redorder the form children to match the ids of the resquest.